# How to repeat a Typing JavaScript function periodically

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, setinterval

I designed a program to type a string into a `div`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var i, speed, thraot, disp;
    i = 0;
    speed = 90;
    thraot = "Jesus is Lord, Forever..."
    disp = document.createElement("DIV");
    disp.setAttribute('id', 'mytxt');
    document.body.appendChild(disp);
    disp.innerHTML = "";

    function myTyping() {
      if (i < thraot.length) {
        disp.innerHTML += thraot.charAt(i);
        i++;
      }
      dd = setTimeout(myTyping, speed);
    }

    setInterval(function() {
      myTyping();
    }, speed * thraot.length);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I know of `setInterval` which repeatedly calls a function at a defined milliseconds, but it doesn't work here.

Please I would like you guys to help me out to making it work over and over again.

Comment: [but it is working ..](https://jsfiddle.net/m1vfc09n/)

Comment: repeatedly, starting from J again after finishing the entire string??

Comment: i tried adding a setInterval to make it work through the string over and over again repeatdly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ha0pq4ek/

Comment: @user0103 Thanks alot... i didn't know to well on await sleep.

Comment: @DanielUko no problem, just keep in mind that it's not actually a real 'sleep', it is  a promise with `await` after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset `i` and your `div` content in the else block.

```js
var i, speed, thraot, disp;
i = 0;
speed = 90;
thraot = "Jesus is Lord, Forever..."
disp = document.createElement("DIV");
disp.setAttribute('id', 'mytxt');
document.body.appendChild(disp);
disp.innerHTML = "";

function myTyping() {
  if (i < thraot.length) {
    disp.innerHTML += thraot.charAt(i);
    i++;
  } else {
    disp.innerHTML = "";
    i=0;
  }
  dd = setTimeout(myTyping, speed);
}

setInterval(function() {
  myTyping();
}, speed * thraot.length);
```

**UPDATE:** Adding example without the `setInterval()`.

```js
var i, speed, thraot, disp;
i = 0;
speed = 90;
thraot = "Jesus is Lord, Forever..."
disp = document.createElement("DIV");
disp.setAttribute('id', 'mytxt');
document.body.appendChild(disp);

function myTyping() {
  if (i < thraot.length) {
    disp.innerHTML += thraot.charAt(i);
    i++;
  } else {
    disp.innerHTML = "";
    i=0;
  }
  dd = setTimeout(myTyping, speed * thraot.length);
}

myTyping();
```

Comment: This example will run everytime a bit faster.

Comment: Yes. It's unclear if that's desired. If not, remove the interval and call `myTypings()` instead.

Comment: Oooh Thanks man i gat your logic. It worked for me, but increasingly accelerating in Speed...

Comment: See second example.

Comment: The second example multipled the thraot.length and speed, and used it against my setTimeout() function. So it is not accepted please.

Comment: It seems that your issue was rooted in not resetting the `innerHTML` of the div and your `i` variable. You can set the timeout to whatever you want. If you don't want it to be `speed * thraot.length`, change it.

Comment: Thanks, alot. It has been fixed... i Congratulate you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `i = 0` before calling `myTyping` inside `setInterval`
If you want to clear the current text, also reset `disp.innerHTML = ""`

Answer (score 0):

I say a big thanks to @user0103, he changed my code into something excellent from good.

How to repeatedly refresh a typing effect function over and over again...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
</head> 

<body> 

 <script>
var i, speed, thraot, disp;
i = 0;
speed = 90;
thraot = "Jesus is Lord, Forever..."
disp = document.createElement("DIV");
disp.setAttribute('id', 'mytxt');
document.body.appendChild(disp);
disp.innerHTML = "";

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function() {
    while(true) {
    for(let i = 0; i < thraot.length; ++i) {
        disp.innerHTML += thraot.charAt(i);
        await sleep(speed);
    }
    await sleep(speed);

    disp.innerHTML = "";
  }
})();

</script>
</body> 

</html>
```

This is working great...